# Use instance of abstract class in cross-platform code

Tags: c++, cross-platform, abstract-class, abstract

Consider the situation, when you create cross-platform multi-thread application.

So, when you do that, you probably would divide the platform functionality between some classes. For example, you need simple console to output some text in your application. The possible way you do this is declare some abstract class `Console` and than, when you need it on some platform, inherit from it and use derived classes instances.

Everything is OK till you find out, that the `Console` instance is needed somewhere(For example as class member). You know, that if you try to declare a member variable of class `Console` in some other class, you would get an error, because the instances of abstract classes are not allowed. But you still do need that class, as you consider that on compilation the derived class will be implemented and it will be correct, but you don't know the name of that class, or there may be different names depending on platform.

Here is the complicated example.

When you develop cross-platform multi-thread application, you need something like `Syncer`(Synchronizer). The analog of it is the mutex object on Windows API.

You know that depending on platform that class would be different. But you do know that there are some methods that any platform variant will has. For example these methods are `lock` and `unlock`. As you don't know how will these methods be done, you declare them pure virtual as next:

```
class Syncer
{
public:
    virtual void lock()=0;
    virtual void unlock()=0;
}
```

And now, developing some class, you realize, that you need not one, but a lot of this `Syncer`-s. But you can't do that, as the class is abstract.

The possible solutions I've found are:

1) Use templates. For example:

```
template<class syncer>
class SyncUser
{
public:
    syncer syncInstance;
    SyncUser()
    {
        syncInstance().lock;
}
```

But the problem is that the class user may paste instead of `syncer` parameter the any other class.(Would he will or not, it doesn't matter. He can do this). So that solution is not as good as the general solution is expected.

2) Use macros. If using this way, the contents of `Syncer.h` would be like next:

```
class Syncer
{
public:
    virtual void lock()=0;
    virtual void unlock()=0;
}
#ifdef PLATFORM1
#include "platform1_sync_implement.h"
#else
#include "platform2_sync_implement.h"
#endif
```

when the `"platform1_sync_implement.h"` file has the following:

```
#include "Syncer.h"

class SyncPlatform1 : public Syncer
{
    //Correct implementation
}

#define Syncer SyncPlatform1
```

Now, anyone included `Syncer.h` would have the the implemented version.
But this way is also not good, as requires the list of platforms, where the `Sync` abstraction will be implemented. That is not so good for big projects, as you just need to declare that class and care about that other programmers could use it.

**So the question is: is there a better way to use the 'instance' of abstract class, knowing that its child class would be implemented somewhere.**

P.S.: I know that that is not the best name for such question.
P.P.S.: Sorry for bad English.

Comment: tl;dr .. short answer is there is no "instance of an abstract class". By definition abstract classes cannot be instantiated

Comment: I'm not convinced by your motivation. Virtual-function polymorphism is for handling different implementations *at runtime*. The use case of supporting multiple platforms doesn't seem to have any runtime decisions. Your program isn't executing *at the same time* on a gameboy and on a playstation. Rather, you recompile for each platform.

Comment: actually I dont understand the problem, if you want an object that is derived from an abstract class as member of another class, you can have a pointer to that abstract class as member

Comment: @KerrekSB, so what way should I choose, if I need to create something, that is not fully implemented now?

Comment: @tobi303, I know I can. But having that pointer you would not be able to create new instances:you can't copy them or call constructor, as the type you class you deal with is abstract. And my problem is that I need to create a lot of instances of class, that would be implemented somewhere else.

Comment: @VolodymyrSendetskyi: Usually you'd factor the arch specific stuff out into separate directories and then select the right one in your build system based on the chosen target architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have different implementations on different platforms, you should not use polymorphism, you should rather use good old #if __linux__, #if defined __mac__ && defined __darwin__, #if _WIN32, etc.

If you need to get the most out of the actual CPU the program eventually happens to run on, and you want implementations specially optimised for each possible CPU, then that's a different story because you need some runtime mechanism to select the best implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind an  abstract class is to provide a point for completing the base class but in the future by the user of the base class.

If that's what's intended then use the abstract class. If the base class should be usable as-is then provide an empty routine

```
class BASE {
public:
    void SomethingUnusedHere() {}
};
```

The user can do the same if it really doesn't matter what the routine does and is still not needed in the using class.

```
class BASE {
  :
    void Func() = 0;
  :

}

class CHILD : public BASE {
  :
    void Func() {}
  :
}
```

Of course, if Func is really needed then it should include the proper code;

Comment: The problem is that I only have the declaration of base class, but the child class should be used. If using your example, the `CHILD` constructor has to be called somewhere, what is impossible if using `BASE` as member variable.

Comment: No. I hinted that the  child class could implement an empty function, as well. I'll edit to include an example of that.